# What is Poisson density multiplied by integer-Gaussian?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

What is Poisson density multiplied by integer-Guassian?

$$p(X=x)\propto\frac{\theta^x}{x!}\exp(-x^2),\quad x\in\mathbb{N}$$

Is it a distribution being studied?

Comment: It's also unclear what you seek when you say "what is...". Assuming you can resolve Artem's question, what is it you want to know about the resulting pmf? Are you seeking a name for it, or some property of it?

Comment: I don't see how "Poisson multiplied by Gaussian" describes this pdf. It's identical to the Poisson pdf except that it uses exp(-x^2) instead of exp(-x). I've never heard of any use for that distribution.

Comment: @HeleneHoegsbroThygesen Poisson is $\exp\left(-\theta\right)$